# Delete data of product_id from whole database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-delete

I have data of products in many tables. and I want to delete all this data by a product_id from their tables. But don't want to use many queries.

*For Example*

```
1. delete from tbl_product_attributes where product_id = 'this'
2. delete from tbl_product_barcode where product_id = 'this'
3. delete from tbl_product_images where product_id = 'this'
4. delete from tbl_product where product_id = 'this'
```

I just want a one query that delete all my relative data of specific given product_id from a database. just like this

```
Delete data from whole DB where product_id = 'this'.
```

*Note:* And also this query not burden on my server.

Is there any way?

Comment: This is where you setup up relationships (foreign keys) and cascade deletes.

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: Are you using InnoDB? If so, you should look into foreign key constraints.

Comment: @Exterminator .. i am using php codeigniter and mysql

Comment: @jeroen ... yes

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
DELETE T1, T2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.key = T2.key
WHERE condition;
```

Also, you can define foreign key constraints on the tables with ON DELETE CASCADE option.

Then deleting the record from parent table removes the records from child tables.

Check this link : [Mysql delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)